# android radiobutton button accept

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a problem with button `Set Color`. `Set Color` is to activate the selected `RadioButton`. For example, selecting the first radiobutton and when you click "Set Color" is the background color change to red. Here is my Android Studio codes.

UPDATE

My app working process now:

When I click for example on first RadioButton  my textview background color change automatically. Its skipping my "Set Color" button.

My intended  app working.

When I click for example on first RadioButton and after that I accept my choose clicking "Set Color" button my textview background color  change.

**XML file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/czerwonyguzik"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/czerwonyguzik"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Czerwony"
            android:onClick="onRadioClicked" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/bialyguzik"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/White"
            android:onClick="onRadioClicked" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/niebieskiguzik"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/Niebieski"
            android:onClick="onRadioClicked" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setcolor"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set Color" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="anulacjaopcji"
            android:text="Anuluj" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textwju"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="101dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**JAVA file**

```
public class LinearLayout extends ActionBarActivity {

    RadioGroup rg;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_linear_layout);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textwju);
        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);


    }

    public void onRadioClicked(View view) {
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textwju);

        // czy guzik jest wcisniety
        boolean wcisniety = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        //sprawdzenie ktory guzik jest wcisniety
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.czerwonyguzik:
                if (wcisniety)
                    textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Czerwony));

                break;
            case R.id.bialyguzik:
                if (wcisniety)
                    textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.White));
                break;
            case R.id.niebieskiguzik:
                if (wcisniety)
                    textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Niebieski));
                break;
        }

    }

    public void anulacjaopcji(View view) {
        rg.check(R.id.czerwonyguzik);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Czerwony));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_radio_button, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You question is not clear what you want >

Comment: It didn't work only for the first radiobutton press?

Comment: @ghosttalker now when i click to one of radiobuttons my <textview> background automatically change. I want to change this, i want first click one of radiobutons aftert that i want click "set color" and then my <textview> backgroud must change. "Set Color" button means "Accept".

Comment: do you want to set a background image instead of color ? its not clear

Comment: No, my radiobuttons have own colors for example first have red color background. When i click on first radiobutton and after that i click on button "Set Color" my Textview background colour change for red. Now when i click on radiobutton my textview change, skipping my "Set color" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
RadioButton radioButton1, radioButton2, radioButton3;
Button setColorButton, cancelButton;
TextView textwju;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.radiobutton_example);


    radioButton1   = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.czerwonyguzik);
    radioButton2   = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.bialyguzik);
    radioButton3   = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.niebieskiguzik);
    setColorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setcolor);
    cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    textwju        = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textwju);



    setColorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(radioButton1.isChecked()) {
                textwju.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            } else if(radioButton2.isChecked()) {
                textwju.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            } else if(radioButton3.isChecked()) {
                textwju.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            }

        }
    });

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            radioButton1.setChecked(true);

        }
    });
}
```

And don't forget to remove `android:onClick="onRadioClicked"` from the radio buttons in the xml.

Comment: @Michał Ondycz How about now? If my answer helped, please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create field for saving textview color in, and just save in it new value on `onRadioClicked`. After you click your "Set Color" call your `textView.setBackgroundColor(savedColor)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the option selected by

```
int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
int radioId = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
String optionText = 
(RadioButton)group.getChildAt(radioId)).getText().toString();
```

now you can do what ever you want
hope this helps